# Adding oracle database as ADO.NET model to visual studio

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2012, ado.net, odac

I was following this guide:

http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm

I have visual studio 2012, external oracle database, Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC).

Now I am trying to add my database, and it asks me first to make a connection, but do not have a spot where to enter my external address.

[image]

There is dropdown to select Data source name, but it is empty.
So basically, where can I enter my external ip to oracle DB, for example : **62.44.121.211**

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem.  The only difference I see is your Data Source says "Oracle DAtabase (ODP.NET, Unmanaged Drive)" where as mine has "Managed Drive" on the end. I also have a blank Data Source Name dropdown and if I pick EZConnect as the option then I get an "OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution" thew an exception message when I try to test the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Connection Type to `EZ Connect` and then you can add database connection info.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right Data Source.
Did you install only ODAC, or also ODT? ODT (Oracle Developer Tools) is the package that adds the plugins to VS, and not ODAC - which is just an ADO implementation, in the case of .net.

After you'll install the right package - the Data source will be "Oracle Database (Oracle ODP.NET)".

When you'll use the right driver the "data source name" field would be the first, and it would be editable.

Any way - for your driver (which I recommend you to update to Oracle's one!) try to check the advance tab (not sure if you could edit it from there).

---

Another thing - in older versions of ODP - you had to add the database you wanted to connect to the TNSNAMES.ORA file - of the client that the ODP is being hosted in,

Please try adding a record to the TNSNAMES.ORA of the ODP.NET Oracle Home with the database you want to connect to.

this is how a record should look in the TNSNAMES:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/how-do-i-generate-a-tnsnames-ora-file-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database

Comment: I download ODAC from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html, which includes `Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 12.1.0.1.2`. Also the datasource, which I have selected `Oracle Database (ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver)` came after intalling the ODAC. So it seems to be the right thing.

Comment: the unmanaged package is an old one, the current driver Oracle distribute is supposed to be a managed one... 

any way - I am editing the reply with an issue that might be your issue.. (and just remembered existed in old versions)